# Lunar logs me out when I switch to regular Minecraft launcher? (Minecraft java)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, for example, if I play on Lunar client, then I switch to the Minecraft launcher I'm logged out and have to log back in, then when I'm logged into the Minecraft launcher and switch to lunar client it logs me out of lunar client please help me find a fix.

Comment: I suggest not using lunar, its quite shady.

Comment: @valkyrie_pilot I would disagree because joining a single game of hypixel bedwars and pressing tab shows that 70% - 80% of people in-game are using Lunar. Not only that but it is really useful.

Comment: If all your friends jumped off a bridge, would you too? their privacy policy allows them to take a screenshot of your computer at *any* time

Answer (score 0):

Currently I believe there is no fix, as I am also experiencing the same problem. Make sure your logging in with your email on lunar as I made that mistake before.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me. I would get logged out of normal launcher and Lunar, the fix for me was closing lunar with the X inside of the client not the premade windows one.

Answer (score -4):

There is a fix: make a new lunar client directory that's not in `.minecraft`.

To do this, go into Lunar Client launcher, and open the settings. Change the "Launch Directory" by creating a new empty folder and click the choose that new folder in the Lunar Client Launcher.

Comment: Can you expand a little on this?